# Applying for UK visa for European Family permit

Tags: uk, family, permits

I am non EEA citizen and I am married to Italian citizen, my wife got an offer to work in UK, I want to apply for visa to join her by the time she travels.

What will be required from us to provide in order to apply for EEA family permit ?

How much should I declare as my or her account as to be sufficient for immigration office as personal fund ?

Does she have to go and join her later or I can apply while she still outside UK ?

Comment: Do you want to visit her briefly while she's in the UK, or do you want to move to the UK to live with her? If the latter, it's off-topic here, and needs moving to our [Expats site](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eligibility Check out the eligibility rules here

Comment: Your wife has a right to work in the UK and she has a right to be reunited with her family. The usual tourist visa questions like bank balances do not apply.

Comment: You can apply while you are both outside the UK, but you must travel to the UK with her or after her.  With an EEA family permit, you cannot arrive before she does.  Read the information from DumbCoder's link, and then if you still have questions, ask them on expatriates.stackexchange.com (assuming that you do in fact intend to move to the UK).